# I tried installing Manim on my Mac but after running the command i get a subprocess error message

Tags: subprocess

I am trying to install Manim on my Mac and when I try running the command to install it but instead it gives me this note: "note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip." Also, I already installed all the other required dependencies. Thank you so much for your help guys!

I tried running the command again and it did not change things.